# SQLAlchemy select by custom column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy model with custom ID in UUID format

```
class Email(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Email'

    id = Column(UUID(), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    raw_email = Column(Text)
```

and when I try to get some object by ID

```
session.query(Email).get("0c7a2a97-c93b-4f26-9408-25d2bf597bc0")
```

it returns an error

```
can't escape UUID to binary
```

I understand that a problem in a custom ID because ID is UUID type, but can I create some preprocessor or another similar thing that gives me an opportunity to select objects using `str`. Because convert str to UUID every time that I need to select some object will be so annoying

I create own function for this converting

```
def str_to_uuid(value):
    uuid = UUID()
    return uuid.process_bind_param(value)
```

and it will be so helpful if I can decorate ID to use this function.

Or it's a bad style to do like this ?

Comment: Is that the [Postgresql specific UUID type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID) or something else?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes, this type of Column I used in PostgreSQL

Comment: Your answer would give the impression that you're using a custom type, instead of `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä as far as I tried this lib `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID`, it didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I understand why I have a problem with this.

```
class UUID(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.LargeBinary

    def __init__(self):
        self.impl.length = 16
        types.TypeDecorator.__init__(self, length=self.impl.length)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect=None):
        if value and isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
            return value.bytes
        elif value and isinstance(value, str):
            return uuid.UUID(value)
        elif value:
            raise ValueError('value %s is not a valid uuid.UUID' % value)
        else:
            return None

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect=None):
        if value:
            return uuid.UUID(bytes=value)
        else:
            return None

    def is_mutable(self):
        return False
```

This is my implementation of UUID Column type. And my mistake was in 
`process_bind_param`. I forgot to add `bytes` to

```
elif value and isinstance(value, str):
            return uuid.UUID(value)
```

So I fix this problem when I change method to

```
def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect=None):
        ...
        elif value and isinstance(value, str):
            return uuid.UUID(value).bytes
        elif value:
            raise ValueError('value %s is not a valid uuid.UUID' % value)
        else:
            return None
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this in flask-sqlalchemy and seems to be of no issue.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import desc, func

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True,
         server_default=func.uuid_generate_v4())
```

Comment: can you please say what version of sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy did you use?

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
sqlalchemy==1.1

Comment: Hmm very interesting... In my project Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2 and sqlalchemy==1.1.11 but I got an exception that UUID didn't found.

Comment: Should be there see docs:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-data-types